# How to include static resources in IntelliJ from external source?

Tags: intellij-idea, embedded-resource

At my work every project ha have two parts:
 1. The project itself;
 2. A external folder containing the JS, images and css.

We have an automated process that deploys this parts where they have to be. The first one at Weblogic and the second at Tomcat.

What I want to know is if there is a way to include this external folder with the application statics to the IntelliJ so I can edit them inside the IDE.

Now I'm editing the JS and CSS inside Notepad. And it is very annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create another project via File -> Import Project, locate the folder of your static resources, then choose "Create project from existing resources".

You will end up with two projects but it should be easy to toggle between the two.

Comment: That way I could edit the files but I was thinking in a way to keep the view of the project open and edit the JS or CSS.
Anyway, thanks for the answer.

Comment: What you want is possible by adding another Content Root to your project. Go to Project Structure -> Modules -> Sources. Click on Add Content Root and locate the root folder of your static resources. Mark the folder as source folders. You should then be able to access the static resources from your existing project.